# sorting clustring key in cassandra

Tags: django, sorting, cassandra, cql

I use `cqlengine` to work with `cassandra` in `django`

```
class vpsInfo(Model):
    ip=columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    Date=columns.DateTime(primary_key=True)
    RecordCount=columns.Integer()
```

I want to sort vps by date desc but I see this problem when sorting:

```
select * from vpsinfo where ip='127.0.0.1' order by Date
```

error is :
unknown column Date;

Can Some one help me?